# How to add color to component tags in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am learning React, and I observe some people made the color of Component tags different from normal HTML tags under JSX format. However I am not really able to find extensions that do this (tried prettier and react snippets etc.). I wonder what enables that behavior?

[image]

Comment: How about color the tag name? It's an extension in vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a built-in Visual Studio Dark+ default dark theme.
Color the tag name proposed by Alex also works, just different colors.

Answer (score 4):

In "settings.json":

```
"textMateRules": [
    {
        "name": "component tags",
        "scope": [
            "entity.name.tag", // HTML tags
            "support.class.component", // JSX/TSX Component tags
        ],
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "red",
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Babel extension fixed it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Add Babel JavaScript extension